# How can I configure mail.mydns.com in my server to go to a third party mail server?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, domain-name-system, windows-server-2012

I just routed my dns A Record to go to my server's ip.

The thing is, in that server (lets say 121.0.0.1) I do not have a mail service running/ listening on any port so I hired a third party mail server to manage my mail.

What I want to do is that when someone tries to send to or from mail.mydns.con instead of trying to find a mail server on MY server, lets say 121.0.0.1, it goes to the one I just hired..

I am new to configuring servers but this should be possible.. I am running a Windows Server 2012.

Comment: Didn't they give you the correct information to use?

Comment: They gave me the ip to which I should send all the mail.mydns.com requests

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the proper [MX record(s)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record) in your DNS zone and point them to the mail server.

Then configure your mail server to accept mail for this domain, if you haven't already. This isn't really any different that configuring mail flow for an on-premise installation.

Comment: This answer really pointed me in the right way..though I am using windows azure and I need to access the load balancer in order to do this and I see no way to do it :(

Answer (score 0):

You should configure MX Records for your DNS Zone. Set them properly with its priority.
In Windows you can do it from DNS Manager.

Check out this link [1](http://gopalthorve.com/create-dns-resource-record-windows-server/) it will be helpful for you.